# An impressible person who other people can have their own impact on them

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What do you call a person (not merely a young one) who seems to be easy to influence. Someone who others can have their own effect and impact on them in many aspects of their lives:

> He is a very **[impressible](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impressible)** person.
>
> He is a very **[impressionable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impressionable)** person.
>
> He is a very **[susceptible](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/susceptible)** person.
>
> He is a very **[malleable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/malleable)** person.

Based on above links' definitions, you'll see that they can indicate this message about someone, but which one can be used in common and everyday speech? (Of course what I am looking for in my own language is considered a formal word too, but most of the people would understand it even not well educated people.)

Comment: "impressionable" is the most natural-sounding one to my ear

Comment: @A-friend :Do you mean to ask someone who gets easily influenced by others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *impress* can mean either to delight someone with an achievement OR to press against something in order to apply or stamp a pattern.

*Impression* can mean either an instance where someone was delighted OR an instance where a pattern was stamped on something.  When *impression* is used with a persion, the first meaning will be assumed.  *Impressible* doesn't strongly have such a "default" assumption without context, so it will probably sound weird.  The phrase *easy to impress* or *impressionable* should be used instead.

*Susceptible* is synomymous with *weak against* and doesn't mean the same as *impress* unless you say "He is very susceptible to being impressed.*

*Malleable* is a term applied to objects, particularly metal objects, meaning they can easily be *physically* bent and changed into different forms.  You can use this figuratively if the context supports it, but a physical method of being "bent" will likely be assumed unless you specify otherwise.  E.g. "His impression of others was easily malleable."